# How is this upper triangular in row-echelon form?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading this text:

[image]

How is the matrix:

\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 0 & -2 \end{pmatrix} in row echelon form? The last row doesn't have a leading 1!

This is the definition of row-echelon form vs reduced row-echelon form in my text. Is this not right?

$\phantom{}{}{}{}$
[image]

Comment: Divide it by minus two!

Comment: Do not confuse the term "*Row Echelon Form*" with the term "**Reduced** *Row Echelon Form.*"  Only in the reduced row echelon form do we require the pivots to be equal to $1$.

Comment: https://stattrek.com/matrix-algebra/echelon-form.aspx @JMoravitz

Comment: As an aside, you could if you desired, still use the definition of row echelon form you cite... the example just needs to be taken a step or two further.  This would lead you to an alternate LU decomposition as being:  $\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\3&-2\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Row-echelon form doesn’t require that the leftmost nonzero element of a row be $1$. It simply has to be strictly farther right than the leftmost nonzero element of the preceding row (and, of course, that all zero rows come after all nonzero rows). That said, some texts do insist on a leading $1$. The text you’ve quoted isn’t one of them.

Comment: The leading term being one is a requirement of *reduced* row echelon form

Comment: Are you sure about this?

Comment: https://stattrek.com/matrix-algebra/echelon-form.aspx

Comment: @Jwan622 Quite sure, although some texts do insist on a leading $1$. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form for a discussion.

Comment: @Jwan622 See the note on the web page you’ve cited.